# Independent sets in graphs with girth $\ge g$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

A well known off-diagonal Ramsey result says that every $C_3$-free graph $G$ on $N$ vertices has an independent set of size $\Omega(\sqrt{N\log N})$.

It is a conjecture of Erdos that every $C_4$-free graph $G$ on $N$ vertices has an independent set of size $\Omega(N^{1/2+c})$ for some absolute constant $c>0$.

My question is: is there some $g$ where we know that any $N$-vertex graph $G$ without any copies of $C_3,C_4,\dots,C_{g-1}$ has an independent set of size $\Omega(N^{1/2+c})$ for some $c>0$?

Comment: good answer below but I think here's another which is not self contained...any C_{2k} free graph has at most \approx kN^{1+1/k} edges, so avg degree at most \approx kN^{1/k}. Then Turan bound for independence number says \alpha at least N/(1+avgdeg) >= N^{1-1/k}

Comment: ah that's right, I feel silly not realizing that does the trick. very nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and for any $c<1/2$. Namely, for $\delta>0$ assume that our graph does not have an independent set of size $N^{1-\delta}$. In particular this yields that the chromatic number is at least $N^{\delta}$, thus there is an induced subgraph $H$ with all degrees at least $N^{\delta}$ (proof: remove vertices of smaller degree while they exist, this does not affect the large chromatic number). Then if you consider the neighborhood of arbitrary vertex $v$, you get that it has at least $N^{\delta}$ neighbours, they in turn have at least $N^\delta(N^\delta-1)$ neighbours, and all these guys are distinct if $G$ does not contain $C_3$ and $C_4$, they have  at least $N^\delta(N^\delta-1)^2$ new neighbours which are all distinct if the graph does not contain also $C_5$ and $C_6$, etc. On step about $1/\delta$ you get too many vertices.